# Can't find variable error on Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I have a problem about global variables on Smartface. I create a dataset and I gave a criteria with a value which name is param1. Although I define a variable which name is param1 in Global file, even the code runs correctly I get an error like;

Can't find variable:
param1

*undefined
*1
*global code

As I said, my code runs correctly, but why I always get this error?

Comment: can you share the code of Global.js and can you share a screenshot of your dataset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got such an error like that. Probably, you defined that variable into  the one of the functions that are in the Global file. You should directly define global variables into the Global file.

function Global_Events_OnStart(e) {
    ...
}

--> For example you should define your global variables here, so outside of all the functions.

function Global_Events_OnError(e) {
    ...
}